# XPath Query using NOT, not working

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to figure out how to selected all of the Suppliers who do not have TV as a product. I'd also like an explanation on the differences of your answer and what I have.
I have the following query written:

```
SELECT XMLColumn.query('/SuppliersList/Supplier/Product[not(@name="TV")]/..')
FROM Tb_XPathQueryTable
```

This is my table, plus a bunch of other Suppliers.

```
<SuppliersList>
  <Supplier name="Joe">
    <City>Paris</City>
    <Product name="Airplane"/>
    <Product name="Milk"/>
    <Product name="TV"/>
    <Product name="Orange"/>
 </Supplier>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `xpath` you are selecting first the Product and then going to its parent, so it will match the specified example (because the TV Product has siblings that match the same parent).

This xpath should work:

```
/SuppliersList/Supplier[not(Product[@name="TV"])]
```

As you can see, we are selecting Supplier which doesn't contain a Product child with `name="TV"`

Comment: It does work, thanks! Also thank you for explaining it.